# value attribute not recognizable to parameter passed through Subject()

Tags: angular

I have a text box in a component, I want its value to be made blank on click of a button in another component. Say the component in which text is there is called `CompA`, and the component having button is `CompB`. I passed a service in both the components, and made a `Subject()` in the service (called `abcService` ) like so:

`filterValuefeededToService = new Subject();`

in html of CompA, I made a template reference and a function on (input) like so:

`<input type="text" #filtVal feedFilterTextVal(filtVal) />`

in ts file of CompA, i did:

```
feedFilterTextVal(filterValuefeeded) {
    console.log("filterValuefeeded", filterValuefeeded);
    this.abcService.filterValuefeededToService.next(
      filterValuefeeded
    );
```

Now in CompB, where the button is there, I do:

```
this.abcService.filterValuefeededToService.subscribe(
            filterInput => {
              console.log("filterInput", filterInput);
            }
          );
```

And I am getting the full input in the `filterInput`. But when I do

`console.log("filterInput value", filterInput.value);`

an error comes: `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'`

So i do something like:

```
this.abcService.filterValuefeededToService.subscribe(
            filterInput:HTMLInputElement => {
              console.log("filterInput", filterInput);
            }
          );
```

But it doesn't work. Please let me know how do I make the `CompB` recognize that it is a HTML Element, so i can change the value of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<input type="text" #filtVal feedFilterTextVal(filtVal) />` is not valid Angular syntax for a template. Please read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: Subject is a generic class. Since you emit an HtmlInputElement, that should be its generic type. But you're doing it backwards. CompB should be the one emitting an event, and CompA should subscribe in order to set the model of the input to an empty string (and thus clear it).

Answer (score 1):

You should create subject in `abcService` like this:

```
  mySubject = new Subject();
  value = "holamundo!";
```

Then from `compB` on button click push value into subject.

```
  constructor(private _myService: AbcServiceService) { }
  clickHandler(){
     let value = "";
     this._myService.mySubject.next(value);
  }
```

Then from `compA` read the value from subject and update the input box.

```
constructor(private _myService:AbcServiceService) { }
inputValue;
ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this._myService.value)
   this.inputValue = this._myService.value;

   this._myService.mySubject.subscribe((data)=>{
      this.inputValue = data;
   })
}
```

Working Demo : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eukb7o)

Comment: Thanks, but there is an issue. If i type anything else in input and then click on button, it doesn't go off

Comment: @gauravoberoi fixed it, instead of value it should have been ngModel in template file containing <input>

Comment: thanks., it's working. But what if I also want to keep focus of input on click of button?

Comment: @gaurav oberoi I don't think it is possible to keep focus on input because the moment you click on button, input will loose focus. Do accept the answer if it answered your original question to help others in future.

Comment: you might be right. but i think we can focus on input after the button is clicked, that is possible in jquery also, and is a common functionality. Anyways i accepted your answer. Thanks!